# When using Material UI library, I'm unable to change the Image of the template - how to change the random splash to set image?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

So, recently, I've been playing around with Material-UI, trying to get a feel for it. I've been using their 'Sign-In Side' template. Everything is working well, except for one thing. Below is a sample of the template code I want to change (Just note, I have only added the relevant area)

```
 const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    height: '100vh',
  },
  image: {
    backgroundImage: 'url(https://source.unsplash.com/random)',
    backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
    backgroundSize: 'cover',
    backgroundPosition: 'center',
  },
```

Specifically, the `backgroundImage` part. I have a local image saved in the path from this '../Login/BackgroundImg1.jpg' and it is imported correctly. I added it to the bottom of the page to see if it was rendering correctly and it was, but whenever I try to add it to this code - nothing, just a white screen - no errors, just blank.

I've tried every method I can think of, and have scoured Stack, YouTube and other random blogs to try and find what I'm doing wrong. Right now, I'm pretty sure I'm missing something small and just need someone else to look it over.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Please see the changes I have attempted below:

```
image: {
  backgroundImage: 'url(../Login/BackgroundImg1.jpg)',
  backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
  backgroundSize: 'cover',
  backgroundPosition: 'center',
```

},
I've also tried the below since I had imported the image using both url and src

```
image: {
  backgroundImage: 'url(${BackgroundImg1})', 
  backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
  backgroundSize: 'cover',
  backgroundPosition: 'center',
```

},

As I mentioned above, I'm sure I'm missing something simple because I've been staring at this code for a day now.

Oh, and here is an image of the Dev Tools, styles for the element.
[image: Dev Tools - Styles focused on the image element - this is the template as is with no alterations.]

Comment: Hi Nyxerian, could you please post an example of how you edited that "backgroundImage" property? Also, if you use the developer tools in your browser, and focus on that element, what do you see in the "styles" panel? That will help you troubleshoot this issue

Comment: Will Edit the post now with what I have done - and take a screenshot of the styles panel

Comment: Thank you, that would help :) In the styles panel, only the "background-image" attribute is the one that is really useful to see when you apply your changes in the code

Comment: Are you using create-react-app?

Comment: use backticks instead of single quotes when using the imported image that should fix it

Comment: Hi Abdullah, Yeah, I used create-react-app. So, with the backticks, I should use: backgroundImage: `url(${BackgroundImg1})`, instead?

Comment: Yes, that's the problem. Only thing to change are the backticks instead of single quotes

Comment: It worked! Thank you! I knew it was something simple :) You guys are the best!